# jQuery, DOM and on() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with jQuery, DOM and on() method. This is my div:

```
<div class="box">
  <p class="addBox">Add Box</p>
  <p class="remBox">Remove Box</p>
  <textarea name="box[]"></textarea>
</div>
```

And a jQuery code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".addBox", function(event){
  $(this).parent().append('<div class="box"><p class="addBox">Add Box</p><p class="remBox">Remove Box</p><textarea name="box[]"></textarea></div>').children(':last').hide().fadeIn(1000);
});

$(document).on("click", ".remBox", function(event){
  $(this).parent().hide(1000).delay(1000, empty());
});
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a box with two buttons, one of them will make another copy of this box, and the other one will delete the chosen box. Two copies of the box are 'hardcoded' in index file, thus available in DOM from the start.

Buttons do they basic purpose, but DOM structure is getting crazy. If I press the 'add box' link on a newly created box, the new one will show up right after the one I clicked. However, sometimes it will show up at the end of the list. It's the same with 'del box' link, sometimes it deletes only one box, sometimes the one I want and two or three more. What do I do wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `.after()` (or `.before()`), but not `.append()`. That, and your `.delay()` syntax isn't correct.

```
$(document).on("click", ".addBox", function (event) {
    $(this).parent().after('<div class="box"><p class="addBox">Add Box</p><p class="remBox">Remove Box</p><textarea name="box[]"></textarea></div>').children(':last').hide().fadeIn(1000);
});
$(document).on("click", ".remBox", function (event) {
    $(this).parent().hide(1000).delay(1000).remove();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/v5jb8/)**

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you're seeing all of your boxes removed sometimes is that you're appending new boxes to the parents of the `.addBox` item, which is the `box` div -- so you're getting boxes nested in boxes, rather than a bunch of `.box` divs in a row. If you change

```
$(this).parent().append( ... // removed for clarity
```

to

```
$('body').append( ... // the rest of your code
```

You won't get that improper nesting, and your boxes will correctly remove only themselves.